# Django Rest Framework - allow other application to log in

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to share `api/user/profile` API endpoint with other developers so they can take user data and process it in their application. I am struggling with writing python script to succesfully log in to DRF because I am constantly getting `{"errors": {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}}`. I am usually login using DRF browsable API to log in and in React I use JWT to handle user authorization but in this case I user must authorize just to get to `user/profile` API endpoint and I am not sure how to achieve that using python.

Please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong in my script.

```
import requests
import re

def get_csrf_token(response_content):
    # Use a regular expression to extract the CSRF token from the response content
    match = re.search(r'csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="(.+?)"', response_content)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    return None

def login_and_get_user_data(email, password, api_base_url, referer_url):
    # Create a session to handle cookies and maintain state
    session = requests.Session()

    # Step 1: Get the login page to obtain the CSRF token
    login_url = f"{api_base_url}api-auth/login/?next=/api/users/profile/"
    print(f"Login URL: {login_url}")
    login_page = session.get(login_url, headers={'Referer': referer_url})

    # Extract the CSRF token from the response content
    csrf_token = get_csrf_token(login_page.text)
    print(f"CSRF token: {csrf_token}")

    if csrf_token:
        # Step 2: Define the login payload with the CSRF token
        login_payload = {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token
        }
        print(f"Login Payload: {login_payload}")

        # Step 3: Authenticate and obtain the token
        response = session.post(login_url, data=login_payload, headers={'Referer': referer_url})
        print(f"Login Response: {response.content}")

        if response.status_code == 200:
            user_profile_url = f"{api_base_url}api/users/profile/"
            user_profile_response = session.get(user_profile_url, headers={'Referer': referer_url})
            print(f"User Profile Data: {user_profile_response.content}")
        else:
            print("Login was not successful.")
    else:
        print("CSRF token not found in the response content.")

# Call the function with your email, password, and API base URL
email = "t.user@test.com"
password = "testpass"
api_base_url = "https://admin.myapp.com/"
referer_url = api_base_url


login_and_get_user_data(email, password, api_base_url, referer_url)
```